# Remove spacing in dataframe by column in R

Tags: r

I have dataframe that looks like this:

```
     A     B         C      D           E   
 1  3434  4343  -    34   343434   -   545
```

where the signs before the numbers is just a `minus`

I'm using following `gsub` to remove the double/tripple spacing:

```
destring <- function(x){return(as.numeric(gsub("[[:space:]]","",x)))}
FinalDataR <- data.frame(apply(FinalDataRe,2,destring))
```

However occationally some rows get disupted by this. (it turns the row into column)

So how to remove safely the spacing for dataframe by row (or otherwise)? So that the above example is:

```
      A     B      C     D      E   
  1  3434  4343  -34  343434  -545
```

Comment: I'd be more concerned about how those spaces got in there in the first place. What does your raw data look like? How did you read it in?

Comment: Yeah, its due to scraping. Where as this is a loop scraping and this lines is basically the last before the data is written into csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your row is turning into a column because `apply` is simplifying your 1-row matrix into a numeric vector. You would like the simpler

```
FinalDataR <- data.frame(lapply(FinalDataRe, destring))
```

However, I agree with the comments that you should investigate your data source more carefully.

Additionally, if you are encountering strings like "34  - ", where the "-" belongs to the string "next door", you can do some wrangling to "throw" the minuses to the other side:

```
FinalDataRe <- data.frame(A='3434  ', B ='4343 ', C = '-34  ', D = '343434 -', E='535', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# notice the penultimate term has a minus at the end
destring <- function(x) as.numeric(gsub("[[:space:]]|-\\s*$", "", x))
minus_fixes <- c('', ifelse(sapply(FinalDataRe[1,-length(FinalDataRe)], grepl, pattern = '-\\s*$'), '-', ''))
FinalDataRe[1, ] <- Map(paste0, minus_fixes,  FinalDataRe[1, ])
FinalDataR <- data.frame(lapply(FinalDataRe, destring))
#     A    B   C      D    E
# 1 3434 4343 -34 343434 -535
### The minus is now on the E column.
```